Why does specialization of a static variable template result in multiple definition error?
As seen in this answer, duplicated names in separate translation units do not violate ODR if they have internal linkage (declared static) because they actually refer to different entities. Furthermore, explicit specialization of a static template function also has internal linkage. However, as the below illustrates, this does not seem to be the case for specialization of variable templates.
g++ and clang++ agree on the code snippet below. The function specialization compiles but the variable specialization emits an error. Assuming the compilers are correct, why is the variable case different from the function case? A reference to the standard is appreciated.
Files a.cpp and b.cpp both contain
template <typename T> static void foo() {}
template <> void foo<int>() {} // ok

template <typename T> static void* ptr = nullptr;
template <> void* ptr<int> = nullptr; // error: multiple definition of `ptr<int>'

static int a = 0; // ok


This also compiles with the latest version of MSVC.

@Holt "This compiles fine with latest g++..." No it doesn't. Here is latest gcc rejected demo

@user12002570, your demo link illustrates the curious behavior described in the question. The link attempt fails for both GCC and Clang because multiple symbol definitions are emitted for ptr<int>. The interesting part is that no multiple symbol errors are issued for foo<int>(). In both cases, the primary template is declared static while the explicit specialization isn't (and can't be per [temp.expl.spec]p2: "... An explicit specialization shall not use a storage-class-specifier ([dcl.stc]) other than thread_local."

@TomHonermann Yes, I noted the same. Also I too couldn't find that explicit specialization have same linkage as primary template.

Although perhaps expected, it is worth noting that the foregoing Godbolt demo by @user12002570 compiles and links correctly when its variable and function templates (and their specializations) are defined within anonymous namespaces. See demo.

The compilers are not behaving correctly. They should behave as you expect. The explicit specialization doesn't introduce a new name. The name still has the linkage given to it by the primary template, which is internal linkage.
Therefore, the explicit specializations define different entities in the two translation units and the linker should have no reason to complain.
I could find an old Clang bug report here. No luck finding one for GCC so far.

I have been unable to find wording in the C++ standard that specifies that explicit specializations inherit the linkage of the primary template. Can you cite wording from the standard to support your expectations?

@TomHonermann Linkage is a property of a name, not an entity (see https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2.sentence-1). And https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#4.sentence-1 specifies that an explicit specialization does not introduce a name. It's name is shared with the primary template.

just removed all my comments, which were off topic (I read to fast and missed the static keyword in the example.
